# How to open the Jquery autocomplete with a fetching results status bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using the JqueryUI autocomplete. Sometimes the fetching of results isn't immediate so I'd like to notify the user the autocomplete is fetching options that match his query.

My Code:

```
$( "#searchid" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/autocomplete_url.php", 
    minLength:3,        
    select: function(event, ui) { 
           event.preventDefault();
           $("#searchid").val(ui.item.value);
           $("#formid").submit(); 
        }
});
```

How can I make the autocomplete to open a 'fetching results status bar' when sending a request to the web-service that is working on finding the results?

Comment: One approach is to catch the `keyup` event on `#searchid` and show your status div.  When the autocomplete returns the results, hide it again.

Answer (score 0):

This approach assumes you're using an Ajax call to retrieve your dataset, but I've used something similar and it worked ok.

Set up a `div` on the page where you want the message.

HTML:

```
<div id="AutocompleteStatus" style="display:none">Loading data...please wait</div>
```

You then want to catch the key up event on your autocomplete:

jQuery:

```
$( "#searchid" ).keyup(function() {
    $('#AutocompleteStatus').show();
});
```

Then your autocomplete could look something like this:

```
$( "#searchid" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/autocomplete_url.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 12,
        name_startsWith: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        $("#AutocompleteStatus").hide();  // <== HIDE IT HERE
        response( $.map( data.returndata, function( item ) {
          return {
            label: item.name,
            value: item.value
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  },    minLength:3,        
  select: function(event, ui) { 
       event.preventDefault();
       $("#searchid").val(ui.item.value);
       $("#formid").submit(); 
    }
});
```

So the short version:  Key up on your search box shows the div, on the return from your Ajax call (I'm using sample parameter names, your example didn't give any actual names), just hide the div again.